# Can not add user to database in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js

I followed this code from https://github.com/tutsplus/passport-mongo. However when I sign up, it is not adding the new user to the database, thus preventing me from logging in. Can someone explain how I can add the new user to the database when someone signs up?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please note that this is a community about programming questions. Your question, however, is about how to add users to MongoDB which is a question about database administration. However, we do have a sister site https://dba.stackexchange.com where such questions are welcome. I nominated your question for migration.

Comment: @Philipp This doesn't appear to be related to MongoDB admin as this is regarding application users being added via `passport-mongo`, not MongoDB users. But I would say it's too broad because there aren't enough details included in the question.

Comment: @Philipp will the replies show up on this site? Or do I have to visit dba.stackexchange? and thank you for nominating it. I am fairly new to this site so I really appreciate your help.